# Hide directory contents from users with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

How can I hide an entire directory, including all files and folders inside, from being listed.  I would like to give a 404, not a "403 Forbidden." Can I show a default 404 message without using an `errorDocument`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `.htaccess` in the desired directory:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

It serves a 403, but you can handle it like a 404.

(Don't forget to grant local access (`127.0.0.1`))

Comment: How do I restrict this to a directory?

Comment: Just put the `.htaccess` in that directory (it'll only affect that directory and child directories).

Comment: How can I handle it as a 404? Thanks!

Comment: `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` and 
`ErrorDocument 403 /404.php`

Comment: How do I go up one directory? Like `../404.php`

Comment: It's an external redirect, so you have to write down the link from the website root.

Comment: Thanks again, but for some reason, the server cannot access the files from PHP. Is there a different way to allow local access? Thanks!

Comment: It shouldn't be. 127.0.0.1 is always local. Are you sure Apache is properly configured on your new server? What are the specs (OS, services, etc)?

Comment: I don't manage the server. Is there a way I can log the server's local IP with PHP?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is **always** the local IP address of any machine. The only thing I can see is that either Apache isn't configured correctly (it's the service that handles the .htaccess file) or that your server's configuration doesn't even use Apache (Microsoft IIS, or w.e.).

Answer (score 0):

It may be a good idea to use the DirectoryIndex statement in your .htaccess file.

This allows you to show whatever file you want whenever it's accessed:

```
 DirectoryIndex /404.php
```

This will show the page at 404.php whenever someone tries to list the directory contents.